# gradle: Could not find method setIgnore()

Tags: android, react-native

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants

The file says that `setIgnore()` can filter the configuration.

But when I use it, the following error is prompted:

```
 org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method setIgnore() for arguments [true] on object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl
```

```
  variantFilter { variant ->
      def names = variant.flavors*.name
      // To check for a certain build type, use variant.buildType.name == "<buildType>"
      if (names.contains("minApi21") && names.contains("demo")) {
          // Gradle ignores any variants that satisfy the conditions above.
          setIgnore(true)
      }
  }
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `setIgnore(true)` on `variant` variable.

```
variant.setIgnore(true)
```